# Multiple access to mmap objects in python

Tags: python, multithreading, mmap

I have a number of files, mapped to memory (as `mmap` objects). In course of their processing each file must be opened several times. It works fine, if there is only one thread. However, when I try to run the task in parallel, a problem arises: different threads cannot access the same file simultaneously. The problem is illustrated by this sample:

```
import mmap, threading

class MmapReading(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10000):
            content = mmap_object.read().decode('utf-8')
            mmap_object.seek(0)
            if not content:
                print('Error while reading mmap object')

with open('my_dummy_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello world')
with open('my_dummy_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    mmap_object = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot = mmap.PROT_READ)

threads = []
for i in range(64):
    threads.append(MmapReading())
    threads[i].daemon = True
    threads[i].start()
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    if thread != threading.current_thread():
        thread.join()

print('Mmap reading testing done!')
```

Whenever I run this script, I get around 20 error messages.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem, other then making 64 copies of each file (which would consume too much memory in my case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `seek(0)` is not always performed before another thread jumps in and performs a `read()`.

1. Say thread 1 performs a read, reading to end of file; `seek(0)` has
   not yet been executed.
2. Then thread 2 executes a read. The file pointer in the mmap is still
   at the end of the file. `read()` therefore returns `''`.
3. The error detection code is triggered because `content` is `''`.

Instead of using `read()`, you can use slicing to achieve the same result. Replace:

```
    content = mmap_object.read().decode('utf-8')
    mmap_object.seek(0)
```

with

```
    content = mmap_object[:].decode('utf8')
```

`content = mmap_object[:mmap_object.size()]` also works.

Locking is another way, but it's unnecessary in this case. If you want to try it, you can use a global `threading.Lock` object and pass that to `MmapReading` when instantiating. Store the lock object in an instance variable `self.lock`. Then call `self.lock.acquire()` before reading/seeking, and `self.lock.release()` afterwards. You'll experience a very noticeable performance penalty doing this.

```
from threading import Lock

class MmapReading(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, lock):
        self.lock = lock
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self): 
        for i in range(10000):
            self.lock.acquire()
            mmap_object.seek(0)
            content = mmap_object.read().decode('utf-8')
            self.lock.release()
            if not content:
                print('Error while reading mmap object')

lock = Lock()
for i in range(64):
    threads.append(MmapReading(lock))
.
.
.
```

Note that I've changed the order of the read and the seek; it makes more sense to do the seek first, positioning the file pointer at the start of the file.

Comment: I understand, what happens. The question is: how to avoid it?

Comment: @mhawke, Why does slicing give better performance? Idid a few quick google searches, found next to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see where you need mmap to begin with. mmap is a technique to share data *between processes*. Why don't you just read the contents into memory (once!) e.g. as list? Each thread will be then accessing the list with it's own set of iterators. Also, be aware of the GIL in Python which prevents any speedup from happening using multithreading. If you want that, use multiprocessing (and *then* a mmaped file makes sense, but is actually shared amongst the various processes)

Comment: mmap also has some other advantages beyond sharing between processes, e.g. efficient random access into a large file where the OS manages the paging.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning GIL. Due to external application call within my actual threads, however, I do get the needed speedup.

Comment: @mhawke Ah, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the single mmap_object is being shared among the threads so that thread A calls read and before it gets to the seek, thread B also calls read, and so gets no data.

What you really need is an ability to duplicate the python mmap object without duplicating the underlying mmap, but I see no way of doing that.

I think the only feasible solution short of rewriting the object implementation is to employ a lock (mutex, etc) per mmap object to prevent two threads from accessing the same object at the same time.